# How to achieve effect of balloon expands with libgdx?

Tags: animation, libgdx

I want to achieve a expanded effect just like a balloon expands. Change from small to big. How can I achieve this with libgdx?

Comment: I've formatted your question into a more readable way (see the checklist [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370)), but it is still unclear. 1: Use correct formatting, marks, etc. 2: Add a lot more details to your question: what you want, what you tried, what doesn't work and how.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Sprites I'd just try to scale them:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setScale-float-float-